# How to print multiple variables in multiple lists separately in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am doing a code on like a speeding ticket program for my practice and I've happened to finish up on most of my program but the only problem is that when I enter in multiple people and try to print the summary, I want to show like their name from the list, the speed they were speeding at and how much fine they need to pay all in seperate print lines but since 'x' number of people can be added to the list, I need something to say that all of them separately. Here is the code:

```
login = ""
user = ["He-man", "Agent_awesome"]
wanted = ["JAMES WILSON", "HELGA NORMAN", "ZACHARY CONROY"]
speeders = []
password = ""
incorrect = 0
max_tries = 3
name = ""
total_fine = 0
fine = []


def security():
global login
global incorrect
while incorrect < max_tries:
    login = input("""Welcome to the Speeding ticket program, in order to continue. Please enter the username (Note: Case-sensitive): """)
    while True:
        if login in user:
            print("")
            password()
        else:
            incorrect += 1
            print("")
            print("This username does not exist in the database, Please try again")
            print("")
            print("You now have {} chance(s) left".format(max_tries - incorrect))
            print("")
            security()
if incorrect == max_tries:
    print("Sorry but have failed to login for 3 times thus you have been locked out")
    raise SystemExit

def password():
global login
global incorrect
while incorrect <= max_tries:
    password = input("Welcome {}, please enter the password (Note: Case-Sensitive): ".format(login))
    while True:
        if login == "He-man" and password == "Open sesame":
            print("Welcome")
            main()
        elif login == "Agent_awesome" and password == "YOLO":
            print("Welcome")
            main()
        else:
            incorrect += 1
            print("")
            print("Sorry {} but that is the incorrect password".format(login))
            print("Please try again")
            print("")
            print("You now have {} chance(s) left".format(max_tries - incorrect))
            print("")
            break
if incorrect == max_tries:
    print("Sorry but have failed to login for 3 times thus you have been locked out")
    raise SystemExit        

def main():
global total_fine
global name
print("")
while True:
    name = input("Please enter the name of the person who was speeding: ").upper()
    if name in wanted: #This checks the wanted list to see whether anyone is in the wanted list and identifies them.
        print("")
        print("{} is WANTED and has a Warrant for Arrest".format(name))
        raise SystemExit
    else:
        speeders.append(name)
        overspeed_input()

def overspeed_input():
global name
global speed_overlimit
global speed_over
global speed_limit
print("")
speed_limit = int(input("What is the speed limit for that road: "))
print("")
speed_over = int(input("At what speed was {} travelling at: ".format(name)))
print("")
calculation()

def calculation():
global speed_overlimit
global speed_over
global speed_limit
global name
global total_fine
speed_overlimit = speed_over - speed_limit
if speed_overlimit < 10:
    print("{} has to pay a fine of $30".format(name))
    fine.append(30)
    total_fine += 30
elif speed_overlimit >= 10 and speed_overlimit <= 14:
    print("{} has to pay a fine of $80".format(name))
    fine.append(80)
    total_fine += 80
elif speed_overlimit >= 15 and speed_overlimit <= 19:
    print("{} has to pay a fine of $120".format(name))
    fine.append(120)
    total_fine += 120
elif speed_overlimit >= 20 and speed_overlimit <= 24:
    print("{} has to pay a fine of $170".format(name))
    fine.append(170)
    total_fine += 170
elif speed_overlimit >= 25 and speed_overlimit <= 29:
    print("{} has to pay a fine of $230".format(name))
    fine.append(230)
    total_fine += 230
elif speed_overlimit >= 30 and speed_overlimit <= 34:
    print("{} has to pay a fine of $300".format(name))
    fine.append(300)
    total_fine += 300
elif speed_overlimit >= 35 and speed_overlimit <=39:
    print("{} has to pay a fine of $400".format(name))
    fine.append(400)
    total_fine += 400
elif speed_overlimit >= 40 and speed_overlimit <= 44:
    print("{} has to pay a fine of $510".format(name))
    fine.append(510)
    total_fine += 510
elif speed_overlimit >= 45:
    print("{} has to pay a fine of $630".format(name))
    fine.append(630)
    total_fine += 630
elif speed_overlimit <= 0:
    print("Please input the correct speed!")
    print("")
    overspeed_input
retry()

def retry():
retry = input("Do you wish to enter another person (Y/N)?: ").upper()
while True:
    if retry.upper() == "Y":
        main()
    elif retry.upper() == "N":
        summary()
    else:
        print("Please enter using 'Y' or 'N' only!")

def summary():
print("Total Fines: {}".format(len(fine)))
????
raise SystemExit


security()
```

So basically, If i enter, Jake Sorrow, speedoverlimit = 30 and fine = 300
and I enter another person like Mark kindley, speedoverlimit = 12 and fine = 80
I want the output to be like:

```
Total Fines: 2
1) Name: Jake Sorrow | Speed overlimit = 30 | Fine = 300
2) Name: Mark Kindley | Speed overlimit = 12 | Fine = 80
```

I know this is a lot of code, I intended to put just the final one but it can't run without the previous functions so please bear with.

Comment: Have you learned how a for loop works?

Comment: Can you cut this down into an [mcve], with the emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: Lookup how to use Python dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another list like

```
fines_list = []
running_total = 0
```

Then append that list as you go, so

```
running_total += 1
fineslist.append("{a}) Name: {b}  | Speed Over Limit {c} | Fine = {d}".format(a = running_total, b = name, c = overlimit, d = fineamount)
```

then print it with a list comprehension or a for loop

```
[print(x) for x in fineslist]

for x in fineslist:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the final part please. Am i supposed to replace 'x' with something?

Comment: Never mind... I got the code to work.....Thank you very much for helping me